# How to get the key value of selected card?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Following is my template code:

```html
<v-item-group v-model="selectedAddress">
  <v-row class="mx-n6">
    <v-flex v-for="{id, title, address} in userAddresses" :key="id" sm12 md6 lg6 class="px-2">
      <CheckDeliveryAddress
        :id="`check-address-${id}`"
        :data-testid="`checkAddress${id}`"
        :title="title"
        :address="address"
      />
    </v-flex>
  </v-row>
</v-item-group>
<rw-button
  class="save-check-btn my-2"
  xs-flex
  color="primary"
  data-testid="saveCheckAddress"
  text="Submit"
  @click="commitCheckAddressSelection"
/>
```

This template uses the following component to display the address in cards. How do I get the `id` prop from the selected card?

```html
<template>
  <v-item v-slot="{active, toggle}" :value="address">
    <rw-card :id="id" interactive :selected="active" dense @click="toggle">
      <rw-card-title>
        <h3>{{ title }}:</h3>
      </rw-card-title>
      <rw-card-body>
        <div>{{ address.addressLine1 }}, {{ address.addressLine2 }}</div>
        <div>{{ address.city }}, {{ address.state }}</div>
        <div>{{ address.zipCode }}</div>
      </rw-card-body>
    </rw-card>
  </v-item>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CheckDeliveryAddress',
  props: {
    id: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    address: {type: Object, required: true},
  },
  data: () => ({}),
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `CheckDeliveryAddress`, update `v-item`'s `value` to include the `id` so that the `id` is propagated to the parent's `selectedAddress`. For instance, bind that `value` to a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) that contains the `id` and `address`:

```html
<template>
  <v-item :value="value">
    ...
  </v-item>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: /*...*/
    address: /*...*/
  },
  computed: {
    value() {
      return {
        id: this.id,
        address: this.address,
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Custom v-item value]

Answer (score 0):

This is the scenario where your child component `CheckDeliveryAddress` trying to pass value to parent component.

This can only be done using event emitter in vue.

So you can do this by

`this.$emit('parent-event-method-name', data1, data2);`

at parent

```
<v-flex v-for="{id, title, address} in userAddresses" parent-event-method-name="methodName"
:key="id" sm12 md6 lg6 class="px-2">

methods:{
    methodName:function(data1, data2){

    }
}
```

CheckDeliveryAddress component

```
<template>
      <v-item v-slot="{active, toggle}" :value="address" @click="raiseEvent">
        <rw-card :id="id" interactive :selected="active" dense @click="toggle">
          <rw-card-title>
            <h3>{{ title }}:</h3>
          </rw-card-title>
          <rw-card-body>
            <div>{{ address.addressLine1 }}, {{ address.addressLine2 }}</div>
            <div>{{ address.city }}, {{ address.state }}</div>
            <div>{{ address.zipCode }}</div>
          </rw-card-body>
        </rw-card>
      </v-item>
    </template>
export default {
      name: 'CheckDeliveryAddress',
      props: {
        id: {type: String, required: true},
        title: {type: String, required: true},
        address: {type: Object, required: true},
      },
      data: () => ({}),
      methods:{
        raiseEvent:function(e){
           this.$emit('on-card-select', this.id);//this.id is selected card id
        }
     }
    };
```

Your Parent component

```
template:
'<v-item-group v-model="selectedAddress">
              <v-row class="mx-n6">
                <v-flex v-for="{id, title, address} in userAddresses" :key="id" sm12 md6 lg6 class="px-2" on-card-select="handleCardSelect">
                  <CheckDeliveryAddress
                    :id="`check-address-${id}`"
                    :data-testid="`checkAddress${id}`"
                    :title="title"
                    :address="address"
                  />
                </v-flex>
              </v-row>
            </v-item-group>
    <rw-button
              class="save-check-btn my-2"
              xs-flex
              color="primary"
              data-testid="saveCheckAddress"
              text="Submit"
              @click="commitCheckAddressSelection"
            />'

methods:{
   handleCardSelect:function(cardId){
      console.log(cardId);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where to put ' this.$emit('parent-event-method-name', data1, data2);' in child component?

Comment: In the toggle method, then emait willraise the event as you click the card, `<rw-card :id="id" interactive :selected="active" dense @click="toggle">`

Comment: What is data1, data2? Can you please re-arrange my code with your solution? I am new to vuejs and not getting you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219434/discussion-between-rajdeep-debnath-and-trupti).